# Can i deal with many files at the same time in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, file, garbage-collection

I have to solve a following problem.

there are many files let's say 3 for example, with the following content

*file1*

a1

a2

a3

a4

a5

a6

......

*file2*

b1

b2

b3

b4

b5

b6

......

*file3*

c1

c2

c3

c4

c5

c6

......

my program has to take filenames in parameter, read those files and print the following result

"a1 b1 c1"

"a2 b2 c2"

"a3 b3 c3"

"a4 b4 c4"

"a5 b5 c5"

"a6 b6 c6"

......

I've already wrote one version of the program, but it start by reading all the files, and that is very inneficient because those file can be 200Mb in size.

how to write a program to retrieve a line in each file and displays my matches before moving on to the following lines in the files. This certainly will avoid loading all the files and make good use of the garbage collector?

**profile images**

sorry i dont know how to insert images here, it always fails, but while profiling, memory usage looks like stairs from the top to the bottom

[image]

ok it's works 1

thanks for reply

**Answer**

Thanks to FUZxxi his answer really help me, but there was a problem when files did not have the same number of line, to solve this problem, I've re-write his program this way

```
printLines :: [[String]] -> IO ()

printLines [] = return ()

printLines ss = do

    ss' <- printFirstLine ss

    if and $ map null ss' then putStrLn "finish" else printLines ss'





printFiles :: [FilePath] -> IO ()

printFiles paths = do

  files <- mapM readFile paths

  let fileLines = map lines files

  printLines fileLines



sliceFirstRow :: [[String]] -> ([String],[[String]])

sliceFirstRow list = unzip $ map getFirst list



printFirstLine :: [[String]] -> IO ([[String]])

printFirstLine ss = do

  let (fline,lline) = sliceFirstRow ss

  mapM_ putStrLn fline

  return lline    



getFirst :: [String] -> (String, [String])

getFirst [] = ("",[])

getFirst (x:xs) = (x,xs)
```

Thanks again

Comment: Some IO, such as readFile, is lazy.  Are you sure what you already have would use too much memory?  Have you tested it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
printFiles :: [FilePath] -> IO ()
printFiles paths= do
  files <- mapM readFile paths
  let fileLines = map lines files
  printLines fileLines
  where
  sliceFirstRow :: [[String]] -> ([String],[[String]])
  sliceFirstRow list = unzip $ map helper list where
    helper (x:xs) = (x,xs)
    helper []     = "" -- Your behaviour here
  printFirstLine :: [[String]] -> IO ([[String]])
  printFirstLine ss = do
    let (fline,lline) = sliceFirstRow ss
    mapM_ putStrLn fline
    return lline
  printLines :: [[String]] -> IO ()
  printLines [] = return ()
  printLines ss = do
    ss' <- printFirstLine ss
    printLines ss'
```

Although not tested, it should be good for memory.

Comment: thanks for your help, it's not a homework but a module in one project i'm working on, while testing it appear the following error.    **test_lazy2: test_lazy2.hs:8:36-52: Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda** in the function sliceFirstRow, it seems that it doesn't take all the possible inputs i'm looking for what is going wrong but can you see it again. thanks

Comment: This occurs, if one line is longer than the others, see updated response.

Comment: hi FUZxxi, the type of helper function is not clear, is it helper : String or helper :: (String, [String])

Comment: helper :: (String, [String]). of course. it returns a tuple which is then unzipped.